# Build a sync service for android / ios?

Tags: android, c++, ios, service, synchronization

Currently I'm building an application for android/ios.
This app is written in C++/QML and connects via PHP with an MySQL database-server.

A feature I really want to have build in is the ability to sync the mobile device with the database (mainly for updates from other users) while the app is not actively running.
I thought the best approach to do this is to write a service that runs independent from the app. This service would be activated when you boot up your mobile device and starts syncing data when triggered by incoming push-messages from the server.

My question is if this is the best approach and if it is even possible to write such a service (with the necessary rights to run from boot) for android/ios according to their policies?

I've read a lot about this subject already, but there are a lot of contradicting answers. That's why I'm a bit lost right now.

Hope you guys could give me some advice/directions on this matter!
(No spoon-feeding needed...)

Thanks upfront!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers are contradicting because things work differently on iOS and Android (unfortunately).

**On Android**, you can write a service, make it run independently from the app, and even start it at boot time.

**On iOS**, however, you cannot write a service, which runs independently from your app (unless you jailbreak). Apple will give your app background CPU time for specific tasks, such as VOIP, GPS fetching, and even background fetching, but you have not the amount of control you would have over your own service.

I had to build an app for Android and iOS which relied on something like a background service, and these different paradigms were a major hurdle.

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot of the **background modes** supported on iOS 8.2 (current version as of this answer):

[image]

**EDIT 2**

If the question refers only to previewing push notifications, on iOS this is possible out of the box. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/) is a great introduction to push notifications by Apple, that shows how you can setup notifications as well as more advanced topics.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly cannot do this on iOS. There is a 'background fetch' mode that will allow your app to periodically fetch updates, but the app has to be running, ie actively started by the user, to do this.

Why do you need it to be a daemon? Can't the app just update when it becomes foreground?

Comment: does that mean that Whatsapp for example, is constantly running even when closed? Because you can see a preview of the message even without opening whatsapp.. That is basically what i need. Because if the app only updates when you open it, i will lose the preview functionality. It would be great if the user would see a preview-notification without opening the app, just like Whatsapp. Or does whatsapp also use this background-fetching service?

Comment: Previews of notifications are no problem, and supported out of the box. You don't need a service for that.

Comment: @Dennis, are these previews also shown without the app running?

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything The app will get notified when a push arrives. But for the preview itself as with WhatsApp it is not necessary that the app runs. Whatever WhatsApp does, you can do it as well.